# Redirect the old url to newly url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am facing a problem in redirecting from old url structure to new url structure

This is the old URL: `https://example.com/user?username=ganesh`

And this is the new URL: `https://example.com/user/ganesh`

Actually I rewrite the old URL to a new URL successfully with the help of the below htaccess code, so rewriting of URL is working fine.

```
RewriteRule ^/?user/(.*?)/?$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

But now I want to redirect all the old structured URLs to a new URL. So, I tried the below code to redirect it but after applying this below code I am unable to access the page with this URL `https://example.com/user?username=ganesh` and I am able to access the new URL https://example.com/user/ganesh

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^username=(.*?)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/user$ /user/%1? [R=302,L,NC]
```

Trying to do this since last 2 days but no luck, Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+user\.php\?username=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?user/([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: anubhava could you please let me know how to handle if there are space in the username and some special characters like dot and small brackets

Comment: Just use `[^/]+` instead of `[\w-]+` in above rule.

Answer (score 0):

@anubava code works perfectly although my condition was a little different.

Previously I was trying

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+user\?username=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?user/([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and Finally, after months I changed it like below and it worked perfectly

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+user\?username=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?user/([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

I don't have much experience with .htaccess but I am writing here, I hope it may help someone.